# How to create one to one relationship instead of one to many in Prisma

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have these prisma models

```
model OrderDetail {
    id        String @id @default(cuid())
    orderId   String
    address   String
    city      String
    country   String
    postalCode String
    phone     String
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
    order     Order   @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model Order {
    id          String   @id @default(cuid())
    createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
    user        User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    userId      String   
    orderItems  OrderItem[]
    orderDetails OrderDetail[] // cant have no arrays
}
```

if I remove the `[]` from `orderDetails OrderDetail[]` I get the following type error in the `order @relation` from `OrderDetail`

> Error parsing attribute "@relation": The relation field `order` on
> Model `OrderDetail` must not specify the `onDelete` or `onUpdate`
> argument in the @relation attribute. You must only specify it on the
> opposite field `orderDetails` on model `Order`.

After removing the `onDelete: Cascade` from `order @relation` the error is this one

> Error parsing attribute "@relation": The relation field `order` on
> Model `OrderDetail` is required. This is no longer valid because it's
> not possible to enforce this constraint on the database level. Please
> change the field type from `Order` to `Order?` to fix this.

I only want to have one-to-one relationship there, not one to many.

How to fix?

Comment: Have you tried the first error's suggestion of "You must only specify it on the opposite field orderDetails on model Order."?

Comment: Yes, I've tried removing the `order @relation` from the `OrderDetail` model and adding a `orderDetails @relation` in `Order`, and also leaving them both added with similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a one to one relationship you have to make `orderId` unique by adding the `@unique` directive. That way it is guaranteed, that each `Order` is related only once from `OrderDetail`.

If that column is not `unique` several `OrderDetail`s can relate to the same `orderId`, making it a one to many relationship.

Comment: Thanks, I already had to make the `OrderDetail?` optional in the `Order` model. But you saved me.

Comment: I also had to add an `orderDetailId String? @unique` to the `Order` model.